# Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0.5^{-}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Finding $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0.5^{-}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n$$
When I want to use the geometric series, I had a problem with $(-1)^n$ so I stoped.

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^n a^n = (-a)^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the comments, I improve my explanations :
when $x$ is close to $0.5$ but less than $0.5$ $0<\frac{x}{1-x}<1$ and hence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{-x}{1-x}\right)^n $ converges. However, observe that when $x$ is close to $1$ or some other number it may happen that series diverges. We should be careful about it.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0.5^{-}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0.5^{-}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{-x}{1-x}\right)^n$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0.5^{-}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x}{1-x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0.5^{-}} (1-x)$$
$$=0.5$$

Comment: Wouldn't a similar argument show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{-x}{1-x}\right)^n\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x}{1-x}}\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1-x)\\=1$$yet $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n$ is undefined ...

Comment: @Foga, I don't understand your point...

Comment: @Timbuc In the first proof we got a result different from the second proof, but they should be the same? Shouldn't they?

Comment: What first proof and what second proof of **what**, @Foga?? In your above comment  you have $\;x\to 0\;$ , whereas the answer and the question is for $\;x\to\frac12\;$ !

Comment: Have you read the whole comment? 1) $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n\\ =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{-x}{1-x}\right)^n\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x}{1-x}}\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1-x)\\=1$ 2) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n$ is undefined (doesn't converge)

Comment: Yes @Foga, I have...and still I don't understand, in particular your last remark: what does that serie diverging has to do with anything? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but are case 1) and 2) the same serie?

Comment: Not at all, @Foga...but then why do you ask whether they should give the same result?

Comment: ok fine!, and where do they differ then?

Comment: @Foga The first one has $\;\left(\frac x{1-x}\right)^n\;$ in the sum, the second doesn't. So?

Comment: yes, sorry I got confused..

Answer (score 0):

Why not to start with $$A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\Big(\frac{x}{1-x}\Big)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\Big(\frac{-x}{1-x}\Big)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }y^n=\frac{1}{1-y}=1-x$$